# Object in low scale not display properly

Tags: transforms

have problem with object when scale it down.
In low scale looks and behave like on gif
[image]
This clip start is adjusted, so looks problem is not with that? When scale it up objets looks and behave normally, like on screen.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the blend file? You can use https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: That looks like Z-fighting to me. Do you have overlapping objects?

Comment: @JohnEason No, it is definitely not a z-fighting. As you see, the object jitters and blends in AA samples. It is a precision error

Comment: ok, got the problem. It is because big x and y coords of location of the object. When i set x and y to 0, then is ok. But i wondering why is that?

Comment: Well, it is a precision error. This is how numbers with floating point works. They have 6-8 digits, that they can handle. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic If you keep object in center - it is ok, decimal point just shifts. But if you have your object far away from center, decimal point can't be shifted.